# setting up tooltips existing on the page and tooltips that get loaded later

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, coffeescript

I have the following CoffeeScript:

```
$ ->
  $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip
    html: false
    delay: { show: 500, hide: 100 }
    placement: 'bottom'
```

This sets up [Twitter Bootstrap tooltips](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips) on page load.  My problem is that I load AJAX links into tabs, and I need to set up tooltips in that AJAX-loaded content.  I thought the solution would be to use `on`, but I can't figure out what element to call it on and what event to use.  I tried:

```
$(document).on 'ready', "[rel='tooltip']", ->
  console.log 'setting up tooltips'
```

But the console message never appeared, so that doesn't seem to work.

I want one chunk of code that will set up any tooltips that are on the page at load time, as well as any tooltips that appear in the future.

**Edit:** [charlietfl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13661456/38743) did it!  Outside of my `$ ->` callback, I placed:

```
$(document).tooltip
  selector: "[rel='tooltip']"
  html: false
  delay: { show: 500, hide: 100 }
  placement: 'bottom'
```

Now my tooltips that are already in the page get set up, and new tooltips that appear in AJAX-loaded tabs get set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap already has delegation method built in. Use the `selector` option to delegate for future elements that don't exist when code is run:

```
$(document).tooltip({
     selector: "[rel='tooltip']"
      /* other options*/
})
```

Reference: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips

Comment: `$(document)...` will work but is the scattergun approach. For efficiency, it's better to delegate to more local container(s) if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a global ajax event handler, like [`ajaxSuccess()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/):

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
    $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip({ //... etc
```

This will run the callback and attach tooltips each time new ajax calls have been successful.

Comment: I actually have a bound function to `ajax:success` currently:  `$('.tab-pane').on 'ajax:success', 'a[data-remote]', (e, data, status, xhr) ->`.  I didn't want to stick the tooltip setup code here because then I'd have it in two places:  once for setting up all tooltips on the page when the document loads, and again for setting up tooltips in the AJAX-loaded content.  I'd prefer to have a single chunk of code that works for both.

Comment: @David, that's concise but inefficient if there's ajax activity other than fetching these new links.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot I agree, it was the first thing that came to my mind. Charlietfl’s answer looks better.